# how to define sort_tuple that returns a tuple in ascending order

Tags: python, tuples

I need to define a function 'sort_tuple' that takes in a tuple and returns a tuple sorted in
ascending order. (I am not supposed to use the built-in function sorted or .sort in the code)

Note: the code should make use of the insert_tuple function:

```
def insert_tup(x, tup):
    b = search(x, tup)
    left = tup[:b]
    right = tup[ b:]
    new_tup = left + (x,) + right
    return new_tup

def search(x, seq):
    for i in seq:
        if x<i:
            return seq.index(i)
        elif x == i:
            return seq.index(i)
        elif x>seq[-1]:
            return (seq.index(seq[-1]))+1
```

Test result:

```
>>> sort_tuple((5, 0, -1, 4, -2))
(-2, -1, 0, 4, 5)
```

Here's my answer:

```
def sort_tuple(tup):
    for i in range(len(tup)):
       if tup[i-1] > tup[i]:
            removed_tup = tup[0:i-1] + tup[i: len(tup)]
            new_tup = insert_tup(tup[i-1], removed_tup)
    return new_tup
```

But this code fails because when i type in this expression:

> sort_tuple((5, 0, -1, 4, -2))

the output should be in ascending order:(-2, -1, 0, 4, 5) but my output is (4, 5, 0, -1, -2).

Comment: You need to specify what help you need. What input are you giving the function, what output do you get, what did you expect instead? If there are any exceptions, include them (in full).

Comment: Thanks for reminding :) and there's no exceptions...the only requirement is to use the insert_tup code

Comment: Where did the `search` function come from? Are you allowed to replace it with one that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do a kind of insertion sort:

```
def sort_tuple(t):
    result = () # start with an empty result
    for val in t:
        result = insert_tup(val, result) # insert each value into its place
    return result
```

This is not terribly efficient, but it is very easy to do with the functions you've been given to work with.

While the code above is very straight forward, in this case it is only working by a fluke, as the `search` function behaves badly (returning `None`) when passed an empty tuple. Fortunately `tup[:None]` is a legal slice. In the specific situation it comes up in, it's even correct!

A better implementation of `search` would return an integer always. Here's a quick stab at it:

```
def search(x, seq):
    for i, v in enumerate(seq):
        if x < v:
            return i
    return len(seq)
```

Or better still, use the `bisect` module to do the searching in `O(log n)` time rather than `O(n)`.